# ExpressionEngine Member Import XML Errors with Apostrophes

Tags: xml, import, expressionengine, member, apostrophe

I am attempting to import to about 2000 members into Expression Engine. I have spent 3 days refining the data into XML. The document now weighs in at over 40,000 lines.

The problem is, some values contain apostrophes (username, screen_name and email address) - which look something like this...

```
<username>BobO'Leary</username>
<screen_name>BobO'Leary</screen_name>
<email>bob.O'leary@example.com</email>
```

This generates the following errors

```
Username contains illegal characters. (Username: 'BobO'Leary' - within user record     'BobO'Leary')
The email you submitted is not valid (Email: 'Bob.O'Leary@emaple.com' - within user     record 'BobO'Leary')
```

I have attempted to replace the ' with **&#39 ;** and **&apos ;** with no success.

I am not an XML expert, so there must be something I am missing.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an XML issue, but an EE issue - usernames can't have apostrophes or any special characters in them. So you'll need to replace all apostrophes within the `<username>` nodes with either a space, dash, underscore, period, or just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use CDATA

```
<username><![CDATA[BobO'Leary]]></username>
```